# How to find a system without an input $x[n]$ is linear or non linear

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, linear-systems, non-linear

The question is this:

$$ y[n] = \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{8}n + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

This is what my teacher said when I asked him for help-:

> In any system, inputs are not given, then we have to assume input is impulse signal. Then the response is impulse response

I really couldn't comprehend much of what he said, but I still tried my best, and this is what I got:

[image: Working by OP]

Am I correct? (I Don't Think so as I believe this should be a non linear system, I have a gut feeling).

Can you help me here?

Comment: Please include the question and your answer, instead of linking to images.

Comment: I don't know how to type mathematics.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Maybe test one of the properties of linearity.  If you multiply the input by a factor the output should increase by that factor:  $f(c*x[n]) = c * f(x[n])$.

Answer (score 2):

$y[n] = \cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}n + \frac{\pi}{4})$ is not a **system**, but a **signal**.

Anyway, if you insist that you have a system with a fixed output $y[n] = \cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}n + \frac{\pi}{4})$, then this will be a **non-linear system**.

Proof is easy: assume an arbitrary input $x_1[n]$ to your system. The output will be $y_1[n] = \cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}n + \frac{\pi}{4})$. Then, assume another input $x_2[n] = a ~ x_1[n]$ , the output will be $y_2[n] = \cos(\frac{5\pi}{8}n + \frac{\pi}{4})$. Then since $y_2[n] \neq a ~y_1[n]$, the system cannot be linear; thus it must be **nonlinear**.